Can I guide Windows search results by adding metadata to programs?
Scenario: I have many programs related to the same sort of task, some of which I use rarely so I forget their names. I want to find them easily.
Wanted solution: I type, for example, "video" into the Windows search box and it shows me a list of video-related programs which I have installed; maybe DaVinci Resolve, Handbrake, OBS, and a few others.
Is there any way to tell Windows search to list those programs from what I type into the search box?
I'm thinking that maybe there is some metadata for programs somewhere that Windows search can use and I can edit when I install a program.

Windows does not support what you describe and I am unaware any third-party application that does what you describe.

@Ramhound That's what I thought, but I was hoping my bing-fu, errr... google-fu was failing me and someone would know better. If no-one comes up with any other answer in a reasonable time, I'll happily accept an answer by you stating that.

Certain file types offer a "keyword" metadata field, but this is not a common thing, and support for that field, or benefits from it, are going to be limited to those applications that care about it, and it won't be usable in the basic Windows search: https://superuser.com/search?q=keyword+metadata+%5Bwindows%5D

A possible work around is to create groups in the Pinned area of the start menu. Then you have a Video collection, and an Audio collection, etc, and you just open the collection to see the applications in there: https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-organize-apps-in-start-menu-on-windows-11

Possible workaround:

Make a folder in the Start Menu for each item type, e.g., Video or Utilities.
Put desktop shortcuts in the folder for each application. Copies of the same shortcut can go in different folders, where functionality overlaps, such as a file converter that works on both video and still image formats.



In Search, type the folder name to select it.
In order to reduce clutter in Search results, make the folder name unusual, e.g., .Video rather than Video.


BTW, it's easy to do this in a utility such as Open-Shell, which can display Start folders on mouse-hover as well as in Explorer Search.

tagspaces.org seems to offer one more solution to your request.
Check the wiki-article Semantic file system to find more names

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
